# Having trouble reseting game to previous round JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, loops, methods

I made a program which asks the user for their pet name and assigns it states of mind for 5 rounds. If the pet gets too angry it is put down.

What I am having trouble with is allowing the user to restart to an earlier stage at the game before the pet died.

Compiling the code would help illustrate the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


class dinoo {
    public static void main(String[] p) {
        Pet p1 = new Pet();
        Pet p2 = new Pet();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);


        String petname;
        String species;
        String angerlevel;
        int thirst;
        int hunger;
        int irritability;

        explain();
        petname = askpetname();
        species = askpetspecies();
        int howmanyrounds = 5;
        for (int i = 0; i < howmanyrounds; i++) {
            int number = i + 1;
            String num = Integer.toString(number);
            print("Round " + number);
            String[] emotionalstate = newarray(5);

            thirst = thirstlevel(p1);
            hunger = hungerlevel(p1);
            irritability = irritabilitylevel(p1);
            angerlevel = anger(hunger, thirst, irritability);


            p1 = setpetname(p1, petname);
            p1 = setspecies(p1, species);
            p1 = setthirst(p1, thirst);
            p1 = setanger(p1, angerlevel);
            p1 = sethunger(p1, hunger);
            p1 = setangervalue(p1, irritability);

            print(petname + "'s thirst level is " + thirst + " , hunger level is " + hunger + ", irritability level is " + irritability + " and therefore emotional state is " + angerlevel);

            if (angerlevel.equals("DANGEROUS")) {
                print(petname + " is looking " + angerlevel + ", get out now! we will have to put " + petname + " down.");

                boolean continueEnd = petdead();
                if (continueEnd == false) {
                    System.exit(0);
                } else {
                    emotionalstate = wheretogo(emotionalstate[]);
                }

            } else if (angerlevel.equals("Serene")) {
                print("He looks  " + angerlevel + ". Seems in a good mood.");
            } else if (angerlevel.equals("Grouchy")) {
                print("You should give him a treat to cheer him up.");
            }

            whatdoyouwant(p1);
            print("Your pets emotion is now " + anger(getthirst(p1), gethungervalue(p1), getirritabilityvalue(p1)));

            emotionalstate[i] = anger(getthirst(p1), gethungervalue(p1), getirritabilityvalue(p1));
            print("Emotional state " + emotionalstate[i] + " has been saved!");


        }


        System.exit(0);

    }

    public static String[] wheretogo(String[] a) {
        Scanner scanner = new scanner;
        print("which level would you like to return to?");
        int number = scanner.nextInt();
        String level = a[number];
        return a;
    }

    public static boolean petdead() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        print("Your pet has been killed. Would you like to continue? (True or False)");
        boolean yesorno = scanner.nextBoolean();
        return yesorno;
    }

    public static int inputint(String message) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(message);
        int answer = scanner.nextInt();
        return answer;
    }

    public static String[] newarray(int arraylength) {
        String[] emotionalstate = new String[arraylength];
        return emotionalstate;
    }

    //takes input from user to cheerup/feed/sing to the animal to lower values stored in setter/getter
    public static Pet whatdoyouwant(Pet p1) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        print("what would you like to do to the pet? (treat/water/sing)");
        String ans = scanner.nextLine();
        Random ran = new Random();

        int reduction = ran.nextInt(6);

        if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("treat")) {
            int hunger = gethungervalue(p1) - reduction;
            if (hunger < 0) {
                hunger = 0;
            }

            p1 = sethunger(p1, hunger);
            print("Your pets hunger has been reduced to:");
            printint(gethungervalue(p1));

        } else if (ans.equals("sing")) {
            int irrit = getirritabilityvalue(p1) - reduction;
            if (irrit < 0) {
                irrit = 0;
            }

            p1 = setirritability(p1, irrit);
            print("Your pets irritability hs been reduced to:");
            printint(getirritabilityvalue(p1));
        } else if (ans.equals("water")) {
            int thirst = getthirst(p1) - reduction;
            if (thirst < 0) {
                thirst = 0;
            }

            p1 = setthirst(p1, thirst);
            print("Your pets thirst is has been reduced to:");
            printint(getthirst(p1));
        } else {
            print("That action seems to agitate your pet, try something else before your pet becomes dangerous!");
        }
        return p1;
    }

    //GETTER METHOD
    public static String getpetname(Pet p) {
        return p.name;
    }

    public static String getspecies(Pet p) {
        return p.species;
    }

    public static String getanger(Pet p) {
        return p.anger;
    }

    public static int getthirst(Pet p) {
        return p.thirst;
    }

    public static int gethungervalue(Pet p) {
        return p.hunger;
    }

    public static int getangervalue(Pet p) {
        return p.angervalue;

    }

    public static int getirritabilityvalue(Pet p) {
        return p.irritability;
    }

    //SETTER METHOD
    public static Pet setangervalue(Pet p, int whatsangervalue) {
        p.angervalue = whatsangervalue;
        return p;
    }

    public static Pet setpetname(Pet p, String name) {
        p.name = name;
        return p;
    }

    public static Pet setspecies(Pet p, String petspecies) {
        p.species = petspecies;
        return p;
    }

    public static Pet setanger(Pet p, String howangry) {
        p.anger = howangry;
        return p;
    }

    public static Pet sethunger(Pet p, int howhungry) {
        p.hunger = howhungry;
        return p;
    }

    public static Pet setthirst(Pet p, int howthirsty) {
        p.thirst = howthirsty;
        return p;
    }

    public static Pet setirritability(Pet p, int howirritable) {
        p.irritability = howirritable;
        return p;
    }

    //Method printing out statement to explain functionality of program
    public static void explain() {

        print("The following program demonstrates use of user input by asking for pet name.");

        return;
    }

    //Method to ask the pet name
    public static String askpetname() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        print("Name your dinosaur pet!");

        String petname = scanner.nextLine();
        return petname;
    }

    //Method to ask the pet species
    public static String askpetspecies() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        print("What species is your pet?");
        String petspecies = scanner.nextLine();

        return petspecies;
    }

    //Randomly allocates thirst value 0-10
    public static int thirstlevel(Pet p1) {
        Random ran = new Random();

        int thirst = ran.nextInt(11);
        setthirst(p1, thirst);

        return thirst;
    }

    //Randomly Allocates hunger value 0-10
    public static int hungerlevel(Pet p1) {
        Random ran = new Random();

        int hunger = ran.nextInt(11);
        sethunger(p1, hunger);
        return hunger;
    }

    //randomly generates a irratibilty value
    public static int irritabilitylevel(Pet p1) {
        Random ran = new Random();

        int irritable = ran.nextInt(11);
        setirritability(p1, irritable);
        return irritable;
    }

    //Method calculates the anger value based on the thirst/hunger/irritability average
    public static String anger(int thirst, int hunger, int irritability) {
        int angerscore = (thirst + hunger + irritability) / 3;

        String temper;


        temper = Integer.toString(angerscore);

        if (angerscore <= 1) {
            temper = "Serene";
        } else if (angerscore <= 3) {
            temper = "Grouchy";
        } else if (5 < angerscore) {
            temper = "DANGEROUS";
        }


        return temper;
    }

    //HELPER PRINT METHOD
    public static String print(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);

        return message;
    }

    public static int printint(int message) {
        System.out.println(message);
        return message;
    }

}//END class dinoo


class Pet {
    String name;
    String species;
    int thirst;
    int hunger;
    String anger;
    int irritability;
    int angervalue;
} //END class pet
```

Comment: Do you have any other information? What have you tried and what went wrong? What is currently happening. Don't expect people to compile the code. Review [ask].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post a [mcve] instead of the full code. Also please look at [ask].

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should look at the compile errors in your code before submitting a question here. 
Please read the links provided in the comments to learn how to submit a proper question.

I tried to compile your code and it had the following errors:

```
java2.java:51: error: '.class' expected
                    emotionalstate = wheretogo(emotionalstate[]);
                                                               ^
java2.java:75: error: '(' or '[' expected
        Scanner scanner = new scanner;
```

That means in line 51, you're passing `emotionalstate[]` , which is emotional state array, whereas emotionalstate itself is an array, so you're passing an array of an array.

So just change it to `emotionalstate = wheretogo(emotionalstate)`

And in line 75, your initialization of `Scanner` object is wrong, change it to `Scanner scanner = new Scanner();`